# How do I convert from HEX to dec having select-string outputs

Tags: powershell, scripting, select-string, powercfg

I'm stuck at a powershell problem - I need to get current active power scheme, precisely Turn off display after ... setting.

I have the HEX settings from powercfg select-object, but I can't seem to figure out how to separate the current AC /DC plans and convert the HEXes. I know I need to convert a HEX to DEC with [int32] but how do I access the HEX?

`powercfg /QUERY | Select-String -Pattern "Turn off display after" -Context 2, 7`

with an output of:

```
Subgroup GUID: 7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99  (Display)
      GUID Alias: SUB_VIDEO
>     Power Setting GUID: 3c0bc021-c8a8-4e07-a973-6b14cbcb2b7e  (Turn off display after)
        GUID Alias: VIDEOIDLE
        Minimum Possible Setting: 0x00000000
        Maximum Possible Setting: 0xffffffff
        Possible Settings increment: 0x00000001
        Possible Settings units: Seconds
      Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000
      Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000
```

Comment: If you want your code to be compatible with any locale you should be querying for the GUID settings otherwise this only works for an English locale. This answer shows an example of how you can achieve that https://stackoverflow.com/a/76553581/15339544

Answer (score 0):

**Preface**:

- For a more robust, culture-independent way to query power settings, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77405287/45375).
- With the `Get-PowerCfg` convenience function from that answer defined, `(Get-PowerCfg).monitor_timeout.AC` and `(Get-PowerCfg).monitor_timeout.DC` would robustly yield the desired results, expressed in *minutes*.

---

The following assumes that you want to **extract the hex numbers embedded in the *last two lines* of your output**:

```bash
[int] $ac, [int] $dc =
   (
     powercfg /QUERY |
     Select-String -Pattern 'Turn off display after' -Context 2, 7 |
     ForEach-Object { $_.Context.PostContext[-2, -1] }
   ) -replace '^.+: '
```

- `$_.Context.PostContext` is needed to access the post context, i.e. the lines *after* a matching one, and `[-2, -1]` extracts the last two lines from it.
- `-replace '^.+: '` removes everything before the hex number from the resulting lines.
- Type-constraining the target variables with `[int]` automatically converts the hex-number strings to integers.

  - **Note**: Using `[int]`, i.e. `[System.Int32]` causes hex values with the hight bit set to become *negative* numbers; e.g. `0xFFFFFFFF` becomes `-1`; use `[UInt32]` instead to avoid that.

Comment: @tomaito, this extracts the hex values in the last two lines, converts them to `[int]` and stores them in variables. I'm unclear on what else you need. What does "replace the HEXEs in the end with the variables" mean?

Comment: @tomaito, one of the things described in https://stackoverflow.com/help on how to ask is to provide the desired result/output. Please edit the question and show what output is desired.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
$powercfg = @"
Subgroup GUID: 7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99  (Display)
      GUID Alias: SUB_VIDEO
      Power Setting GUID: 3c0bc021-c8a8-4e07-a973-6b14cbcb2b7e  (Turn off display after)
        GUID Alias: VIDEOIDLE
        Minimum Possible Setting: 0x00000000
        Maximum Possible Setting: 0xffffffff
        Possible Settings increment: 0x00000001
        Possible Settings units: Seconds
      Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000
      Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000
"@
$results = $powercfg | Select-String -Pattern "Turn off display after" -Context 2,8
$reader = [System.IO.StringReader]::new($results)
$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
While(($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null)
{
   $line -Match '>?(?<key>[^:]+):(?<value>.*)' | Out-Null
   $key = $Matches['key'].Trim() 
   $value = $Matches['value'].Trim()
   if($value -Match '0x[0-9a-fA-F]+')
   {
      $value = [int]::Parse($Matches[0].SubString(2), [System.Globalization.NumberStyles]::HexNumber)
   }
   $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Name -NotePropertyValue $key
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Value -NotePropertyValue $value
   $table.Add($newRow)  | Out-Null
}
$table
```

Comment: One of the suggestions for creating a good answer is to describe how it solves the problem. Code only answers are discouraged. Could you say more about separating the AC and DC plans as well as converting the hex values?